# Add entity label to existing SpaCy model

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I would like to further train the en_core_web_trf model to recognise another entity tag. I'm using SpaCy's CLI as recommended by them.

The training begins with no issues on Google Colab with gpu, I was just wondering if I missed something in my config file:

```
[paths]
train = "train.spacy"
dev = "valid.spacy"
vectors = null
init_tok2vec = null

[system]
gpu_allocator = "pytorch"
seed = 0

[nlp]
lang = "en"
pipeline = ["transformer","ner"]
batch_size = 128
disabled = []
before_creation = null
after_creation = null
after_pipeline_creation = null
tokenizer = {"@tokenizers":"spacy.Tokenizer.v1"}

[components]

[components.ner]
source = "en_core_web_trf"

[components.ner.model]
@architectures = "spacy.TransitionBasedParser.v2"
state_type = "ner"
extra_state_tokens = false
hidden_width = 64
maxout_pieces = 2
use_upper = false
nO = null

[components.ner.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy-transformers.TransformerListener.v1"
grad_factor = 1.0
pooling = {"@layers":"reduce_mean.v1"}

[components.transformer]
source = "en_core_web_trf"

[components.transformer.model]
@architectures = "spacy-transformers.TransformerModel.v3"
name = "roberta-base"

[components.transformer.model.get_spans]
@span_getters = "spacy-transformers.strided_spans.v1"
window = 128
stride = 96

[components.transformer.model.tokenizer_config]
use_fast = true

[corpora]

[corpora.dev]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.dev}
max_length = 0
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[corpora.train]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.train}
max_length = 0
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[training]
accumulate_gradient = 3
dev_corpus = "corpora.dev"
train_corpus = "corpora.train"
seed = ${system.seed}
gpu_allocator = ${system.gpu_allocator}
dropout = 0.1
patience = 1600
max_epochs = 0
max_steps = 20000
eval_frequency = 200
frozen_components = []
annotating_components = []
before_to_disk = null

[training.batcher]
@batchers = "spacy.batch_by_padded.v1"
discard_oversize = true
size = 2000
buffer = 256
get_length = null

[training.logger]
@loggers = "spacy.ConsoleLogger.v1"
progress_bar = false

[training.optimizer]
@optimizers = "Adam.v1"
beta1 = 0.9
beta2 = 0.999
L2_is_weight_decay = true
L2 = 0.01
grad_clip = 1.0
use_averages = false
eps = 0.00000001

[training.optimizer.learn_rate]
@schedules = "warmup_linear.v1"
warmup_steps = 250
total_steps = 20000
initial_rate = 0.00005

[training.score_weights]
ents_f = 1.0
ents_p = 0.0
ents_r = 0.0
ents_per_type = null

[pretraining]

[initialize]
vectors = ${paths.vectors}
init_tok2vec = ${paths.init_tok2vec}
vocab_data = null
lookups = null
before_init = null
after_init = null

[initialize.components]

[initialize.tokenizer]
```

From what I saw online, the factory component should be replaced by the source one, which I did for component.ner and component.transformer. But just before training, while debugging the config file, I get a warning of:

```
⚠ Some model labels are not present in the train data. The model
performance may be degraded for these labels after training: 'DATE', 'PERSON',
'QUANTITY', 'ORG', 'LANGUAGE', 'LOC', 'MONEY', 'WORK_OF_ART', 'PERCENT', 'NORP',
'ORDINAL', 'LAW', 'GPE', 'TIME', 'EVENT', 'FAC', 'PRODUCT', 'CARDINAL'.
```

Does the fact that more categories than the extra one I am training for are needed, means that the config file is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The warning just means what it says - if you train the model but don't include some types of entities it has seen before, it may forget those entities. That's referred to as "catastrophic forgetting", and you can read more about it [here](https://explosion.ai/blog/pseudo-rehearsal-catastrophic-forgetting).

One way to work around this is to add annotations for the missing entities. You can mostly do this by running the NER model you have over a bunch of text, like Wikipedia, and using that "silver" data as training data. This will still have quality degradation, but it won't be as bad. It can also cause issues if non-specialist text includes your new entities.

An easier way, and what we usually recommend, is to train a separate NER component for your new entity. If you want annotations from the standard NER and your component together, you can have two NER components in the same pipeline. See [this example project](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials/ner_double) for details of how that works.